# Why does Chrome not render font-family for a button?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, font-family

I have the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6u3bamv/4/). In Chrome, the button is still rendered as `font-family: system-ui` even though the CSS under Developer Tools shows `font-family: 'Gaegu', cursive`. The issue does not happen with Firefox.

**Chrome 67.0.3396.99** [image]

**Firefox 61.0.1** [image]

Comment: i think `specificity` is your issue input.button-text {
    font-family: 'Gaegu', cursive;
    font-size: 18px;
}  Version 67.0.3396.99 is my version and i am seeing cursive font

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is weird, because when I opened your `fiddle` link I saw:

[image: your fiddle link in my computer]

My system is `Ubuntu` 18.4 and my Google chrome is `Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)` but I think the system is not your problem, maybe the version of your font is not compatible with your `Google Chrome`. but I have a better version of this font that are compatible with all browsers.

Forget about browsers and systems, you must use font embed, I mean `@font-face`. because I didn't see this in your fiddle codes. follow below structure and embed your font to your project and make independent your project from systems and browsers.

1. Download all types of the latest version of your font
2. Put them to a consistent folder
3. Use `@font-face` to declare a embed font in your project

See the below code:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'gaegu_mine';
   src: url('./font/Gaegu.eot');
   src: url('./font/Gaegu.woff') format('woff'),
   url('./font/Gaegu.ttf') format('truetype'),
   url('./font/Gaegu.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

Then use the font normally like:

```
.some-class {
    font: normal 15px/20px 'gaegu_mine';
}
```

Hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @Kaiido in the comments, this appears to be a bug on Chrome 67 for Mac OS X. If I add `-webkit-appearance: none;` to the `input.button-text` CSS selector, the issue is resolved.